# The more pythonic way to call more than one function

Tags: python

I am writing a script (for learning purposes) with functions that can be used when needed.

I have a function that does the reverse of a string given and I have another function that does the complement (replace characters) of a string given. These can be used when necessary independently but imagine that it would be very convenient to have a function that at the same time does both.

What is the more pythonic way to do this? From the command line, shall call both functions, or shall I create a new function that calls them and then from the command line just called the one that calls the two previous ones? I think that the last option is the correct one I mean create a third function that does reverse() and complement() but if this is correct, I am not sure how to do this. Is important the order of the function in the class object?? Could you please put me in the right direction? I am completely new working with class and functions

```
import sys

input = sys.argv[1]
class Sequence:               # Use a class called Sequence
    def __init__(self, DNA): 
        '''
        Stores original sequence
        '''
        self.DNA = DNA
    def length(self):
        '''
        Returns the length of the original sequence
        '''
        print(len(self.DNA))
    def reverse_and_complement(self):
        '''
        Do the reverse and the complement
        calling the function reverse() and complement()
        '''
        reverse = self.reverse()
        reverse_complement = self.complement(reverse)
        print(reverse_complement)

    def complement(seq): 
        '''
        Return the complement of a seq given
        '''
        complement_dict = {"A": "T", "T": "A","G":"C","C":"G"}
        for k in  complement_dict: 
            complement = complement.replace(k,complement_dict[k])  
        return complement
    def reverse(seq):
        '''
        Reverse a given seq
        '''
        reverse = seq[::-1]
        return reverse
    

run = Sequence(input)
run.length()
run.complement()
run.reverse()
run.reverse_and_complement()
```

Comment: Write functions for anything that's needed frequently. So if it's common to call both functions together, write a function that does it.

Comment: It seems fine, although I would return the sequence from the functions (or use the member ‘sequence’), and leave the print-out to the calling function. For such a simple example I wouldn't even wrap it in a class, but that is a matter of preference.

Comment: It's not the issue you're having but don't replace/overwrite builtin keywords such as `input` unless you know what you're doing. This will cause issues down the line.

Comment: Your code errors out in the complement function. `complement` is never defined and I cannot figure out what it's supposed to be.

Comment: see also [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: you could use `self` instead of `seq` - it will be more readable for other users. And you need `self.DNA[::-1]` instead of `seq[::-1]`. But if you want to reverse external data then you should use `def reverse(self, seq):`

Comment: your main problem is inconsistency. Once you runs `run.complement()`
`run.reverse()` without sending any data and getting result - like you would like to work on `self.DNA` - but in `reverse_and_complement()` you use `reverse = self.reverse()`
`reverse_complement = self.complement(reverse)` - like you would like to run it on external data. So you use the same function in two different ways - but you should use them always in the same way.